# Xcode error with slash invert, not compile

Tags: swift, xcode

At my work I have legacy SWIFT code that was edited with Xcode 13.2.1. We recently had to update Xcode to 14.0 in order to compile to iOS 16, but now we're having issues with literals

When I want to compile it gives me errors in multiple parts of the code, where there is a "/" before a variable, but when I check it the lint does not mark the error in some of the cases.

`destVC.phone = ("","" ,/self?.tfEmail.text,/response?.id)`
save me the error `Expected ',' separator`

It doesn't recognize self?.tfEmail.text as a variable because it has the "/" before it, but if I remove it it still gives an error.

Comment: The two slashes should be removed. We can’t comment on the error you receive at that point without details…

Comment: “had to update Xcode to 14.0 in order to compile to iOS 14” … I assume you meant iOS 16.

Comment: Forward slashes represent literal Regex patterns in Xcode 14. You have to refactor the variable names.

Comment: It's like it says @vadian , except I ran into the problem and it was that a custom operator was set with the "/" . Now with the SWIFT 5.7 update it conflicts with the Regex declaration format